# Kotlin: Delegation with generic constraints

Tags: templates, generics, kotlin, typename

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to declare a class with delegation that also has type restrictions. For example, this is valid syntax:

```
open class Cell<T>(val innerList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()) : MutableList<T> by innerList
```

But now I want to enforce that `T` extends `ClassFoo` and implements `InterfaceBar`. Where do I put the `where` keyword?

Here are some things I tried that do not compile:

```
open class Cell<T>(val innerList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()) : MutableList<T> by innerList where T : ClassFoo, T : InterfaceBar

open class Cell<T>(val innerList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()) where T : ClassFoo, T : InterfaceBar : MutableList<T> by innerList

open class Cell<T>(val innerList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()) : MutableList<T> where T : ClassFoo, T : InterfaceBar by innerList
```

Are these restrictions not compatible with delegation? In other words, should I just extend my `Cell` class and place bounds on a derived class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version is correct, but you need to put `where` on a new line (probably a bug)

```
open class Cell<T>(val innerList: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()) : MutableList<T> by innerList
        where T : ClassFoo, T : InterfaceBar
```